# Service is undefined, angularJs unit Testing error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, webstorm, karma-jasmine

I have this error shown, i tried many solution at the net, like this example in http://www.benlesh.com/2013/06/angular-js-unit-testing-services.html, but it seems nothing works.

*****app.js

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','dialogs','ngResource']);

        app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$resourceProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$resourceProvider) {

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url:'/',
                    views: {
  ......}})
  }]);
```

*****test.js

```
     describe('basicService tests', function (){

       beforeEach(module('myApp'));
       var basic;

       // excuted before each "it" is run.
       beforeEach(inject(function(basicService) {
            basic = basicService;
       }));


      it('should make text exciting', function (){
        //var result = basic.exciteText('bar');
         expect(basic.exciteText('bar')).toBe('bar!');
      });
});
```

***** service.js

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('basicService', function(){
return {
    exciteText: function(msg) {
        return msg + '!!!'
    }
};
});
```

*****error

```
minErr/<@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/angular.js:63:12
loadModules/<@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/angular.js:4138:15
forEach@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/angular.js:323:11
loadModules@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/angular.js:4099:5
createInjector@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/angular.js:4025:11
workFn@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/angular-mocks.js:2425:44
createStartFn/<@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/adapter.js:317:5
TypeError: basic is undefined in C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/cportal/component/administration/caFingerPrint/caFingerprintService_test.js (line 20)
@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/cportal/component/administration/caFingerPrint/caFingerprintService_test.js:20:9
createStartFn/<@C:/_Stage/myprojet/src/main/webapp/js/adapter.js:317:5
```

PS: in *karma.config.js*, i added these files.
also, i tried **var app = angular.module('myApp', []);** because i didn't include them in '*karma.config.js*' and i call them like this,

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

so i thougth its the error, but nothing.Thanks for any help.

Comment: could you provide us with the exact error message?

Comment: @DanPantry, i'd added the error

Answer (score 0):

Seems the needed files are not correctly set up in karma.config.js. I can successfully run your test when using the following karma.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {


    var configuration = {
        autoWatch: false,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],


        files: [

            'lib/angular.js',
            'lib/angular-resource.js',
            'lib/angular-ui-router.js',
            'lib/angular-mocks.js',
            'app.js',
            'service.js',
            'test/**/*js'

        ],
...
```

Of course, you need to make sure that all references files are there and specified paths (relative to karma.config) are correct (in my project spec files are in 'test' folder, libraries - in 'lib', application files are located in the same directory as karma configuration file)